# Битрикс стирает из URL www

Tags: битрикс

Ситуация такая: если на сайте разместить внешнюю ссылку с www , то www не отображается. пробовал и в меню сайта и в содержании страницы. временно заткнул дыру короткой ссылкой гугл, но хотелось бы избавиться от столь странного костыля. Кто-нибудь сможет подсказать решение?

Comment: Каким образом вы размещаете ссылку?  Если прямо в код страницы добавить тег с такой ссылкой - то же удалит?

Comment: не совсем. он не отображает ее в своих редакторах и не обрабатывает при нажатии, но если скачать файл, то www на месте

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то тут два варианта:

- если ты вставляешь ссылку через их визуальный редактор, то вставляешь ссылку через панель как ссылка "на другой сайт", там можешь указать полный путь через www и на выбор даже будет протокол http или https
- если просто через редактор, то делай ссылку с полным путем включая протокол, то есть

  ```
  <a href="http://www.link.ru">link<a/>
  ```

  и при использовании визуального редактора он будет видеть всю ссылку включая www и в публичке будет ссылка с www.